# Overlapping pyplot.imshow() plot in single grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I want to plot this figures. For the first figure:

[Figure1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkL8.png)

For the code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
row = 30
col = row
areas_pher = [[-0.01 for i in range(col)] for j in range(row)] 

for i in range(1, row-1):
    for j in range(1, col-1):
         areas_pher[i][j] = 0
max_pher = 20
for pher in range(1, col-1):
    areas_pher[15][pher] = max_pher * pher/max_pher
plt.imshow(areas_pher, cmap="Blues_r", vmin=0, vmax=max_pher)
```

And the second figure:

[Figure2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5LAo.png)

For the code snippets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

areas_ant = [[6 for i in range(col)] for j in range(row)]
prob_ant = 0.05    

for i in range(1, row-1):
    for j in range(1, col-1):
        rand = np.random.rand()
        if rand < prob_ant:
            areas_ant[i][j] = 5
plt.imshow(areas_ant, cmap="Blues")
```

My question, what the best way to make its figures overlapping, for illustrate like this image below?

[Overlapping Figures Illustration.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umzw0.png)

Comment: Note : For matrix dimension of second figure is similar to first figure

Comment: Create an axes in a single figure, use that axes to plot both with `imshow`. To allow both layers to be visible, set alpha value of top layer to 0.5.